# Scrolling in GridLayout

Tags: android, scroll, grid-layout

I am designing an app in which I have to display image buttons in 10 rows and 2 columns, so I chose grid layout design to arrange them. However, I'm having difficulty in linking the scrollbar to it. The code for GridLayout is given below:

```
<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:rowCount="10"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_width="165dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:background="@drawable/navbharat"
        android:id="@+id/navbharat"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="0" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="165dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ajjtak"
        android:id="@+id/ajjtak"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_below="@+id/navbharat"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="1"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_width="165dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:background="@drawable/abpnews"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ajjtak"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="0"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_width="165dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:background="@drawable/amarujala"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="1"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_width="165dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:background="@drawable/dainikbhaskar"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton5"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="0"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_width="165dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:background="@drawable/dainikjagran"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton6" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_width="165dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:background="@drawable/dainiknavjyoti"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton7" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_width="165dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:background="@drawable/googlenews"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton8" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_width="165dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_row="4"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:background="@drawable/aryan"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton9" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_width="165dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_row="4"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:background="@drawable/cnbc"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton10" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_width="165dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_row="5"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:background="@drawable/ddnews"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton11" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_width="165dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_row="5"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:background="@drawable/graminrajasthan"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton12" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_width="165dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_row="6"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:background="@drawable/haribhoomi"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton14" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_width="165dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_row="5"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:background="@drawable/ibn7"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton15" />

</GridLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent">


   <Gridlayout>


     your code


   </Gridlayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

GridLayout it doesn't need any scrollview for this. Elements in a gridview automatically arranged in a fixed scroll view so that you need not implement any additional scrollview to scroll it.